# Add multiple rows in Postgres with on conflict

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I am currently inserting the values in Postgres like

```
INSERT INTO %s.schedule_hours_raw_data(userId, startDateTime, createdBy,
 createdDateTime, day) VALUES (%d,'%s','%s','%s','%s') ON CONFLICT (userId, day) 
 DO UPDATE  SET startDateTime = '%s',createdBy='%s',createdDateTime='%s',

 SCHEMA, shift.getUserId(), shift.getStartDateTime(), shift.getCreatedBy(), shift.getCreatedDateTime(),
 shift.getDay(), shift.getStartDateTime(), shift.getCreatedBy(), shift.getCreatedDateTime()
```

Now I want to insert multiple values, but not sure how to handle on conflict as the values are dynamic. How to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [excluded](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) value, like this:

```
INSERT INTO %s.schedule_hours_raw_data(userId, startDateTime, createdBy,createdDateTime, day) 
 VALUES (%d,'%s','%s','%s','%s') 
 ON CONFLICT (userId, day) 
 DO UPDATE  
 SET startDateTime = EXCLUDED.startDateTime
    ,createdBy= EXCLUDED.createdBy
    ,createdDateTime=EXCLUDED.createdDateTime; -- and other columns
```